# cannot execute binary file while deploying rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Rails app on Heroku and having an error.

I am on macOS and, I have run are

```
replace REPLACE_ME_OS/REPLACE_ME_ARCH with values as noted below 
$ wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-x64.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz 
$ tar -xvzf heroku.tar.gz 
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
$ sudo mv heroku-cli-v6.x.x-darwin-64 /usr/local/lib/heroku
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
```

and when I run `heroku -v`, I am getting

```
/usr/local/bin/heroku: line 29: /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/node: cannot execute binary file
```

Any help?

Comment: If you are able to successfully run the rails server locally then use the heroku UI dashboard to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the Linux version, not the macOS version. Use the macOS installer [available directly from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) or use Homebrew:

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```